# Use MySQL on Raspbian instead of MariaDB

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, debian, mariadb, raspbian

I am building an application server on my Raspberry Pi. One of the requirements of the project is MySQL (Not MariaDB, it's not the same). When trying to install MySQL, I discovered MariaDB is the default database server since last 2017, on all Debian distros. Fine, but I don't want that, I want MySQL.

When trying to search for an answer I only found MariaDB evangelists, and particularly a [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1245617) that says that it can not be done because it involves re-compiling MySQL, for which the Raspberry doesn't have enough memory.

Can anyone confirm whether this is true or false? Is there no way to have MySQL running on Raspbian? And if there is, how please?

Comment: MariDB is a super-set of MySQL which means it has everything MySQL does and more. Is there a compelling reason MariaDB won't work for you?

Comment: Would [this link](https://www.stewright.me/2014/06/tutorial-install-mysql-server-on-raspberry-pi/) help you someway ?

Comment: @Dave no, this is not true. Mariad is a **fork** of mysql which is getting more and more divergent with every release. Both have quite a few features that the other does not have.

Comment: @Dave I am not interested on discussing MariaDB's capabilities, or comparing it with MySQL. I want to install MySQL on Raspbian, period. Thanks for your answer. Also, thanks Shadow for clarifying.

Comment: @GMB No it would not. As stated above, this is happening since mid-2017, and the tutorial you point at is from 2014. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is there a cross-compiler for Raspberry Pi?  That should avoid the memory issue.

Comment: Good shout @RickJames Not aware of any, does anyone know?